# ruby: calling super without having a parent class

Tags: ruby, initialization, parent, super

I have a class which overrides self.new and calls super in it, but the class doesn't derive from antoher class. So what exactly does the call?

```
class Test
  attr_reader :blatt

  def self.new(blatt, quellformat, &block)
    begin
      # why can't I call initialize(blatt,quellformat) here? 
      # when I try this, it only prints "wrong # of arguments(2 for 1)"

      a = super(blatt, quellformat) # but this works...

      # some code
      a
    end
  end

  def initialize(blatt, quellformat)
    @name = blatt.blattname
    @datei = blatt.datei
    @blatt = blatt
    @qu = quellformat
  end
end
```

Comment: What is the `begin`-`end` in `self.new` for?

Comment: Don't override `self.new`. It's a terrible, terrible idea. Use `initialize` instead.

Comment: Besides the fact you _must not_ override `self.new`, calling `initialize` will call class’ function, not an instance one. It sounds like you absolutely don’t understand what you are doing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> why can't I call `initialize(blatt,quellformat)` here?

Because `Test::new` is a class method and `Test#initialize` is an instance method. You need an instance of your class to call `initialize`.

> but the class doesn't derive from another class

It might not be obvious, but your class is actually an instance of [`Class`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Class.html).

> So what exactly does the call?

By defining `self.new`, you're overriding [`Class#new`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Class.html#method-i-new). According to the documentation:

> Calls `allocate` to create a new object of *class*’s class, then invokes that object’s `initialize` method, passing it *args*.

A Ruby implementation would look like this:

```
def self.new(*args)
  obj = allocate
  obj.send(:initialize, *args)
  obj
end
```

Calling `super` simply invokes the default implementation, i.e. `Class#new`, which does the same. Here's the C code:

```c
VALUE
rb_class_new_instance(int argc, const VALUE *argv, VALUE klass)
{
    VALUE obj;

    obj = rb_obj_alloc(klass);
    rb_obj_call_init(obj, argc, argv);

    return obj;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Classes inherit from `Object` by default. Hence, your `super` call will call `Object.new`.

Comment: Generally speaking, this is not true. `BasicObject` does not inherit from `Object`.

Comment: Ah. Nice one. Didn't know `Object` had a parent.

Comment: `▷ Object.ancestors #⇒ [Object, PP::ObjectMixin, Kernel, BasicObject]`

Comment: `ancestors` includes modules I believe, not just inherited parents. `Object.superclass => BasicObject` - `BasicObject.superclass
=> nil`

Comment: ah okay, didn't know that. But why can't I call initialize instead of super there?

Comment: You don't need to call `self.new` if you're calling `initialize`. You can call `super` within `initialize`, though i'm not sure what `Object#initialize` does.